# Solving matrix equation of the form $(AX)^2+(BY)^2=D$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, quadratics, matrix-equations

Is there any method that can solve the matrix equation of the form $(AX)^2+(BY)^2=D$? $A$ and $B$ are matrices, $X$, $Y$ and $D$ are column vectors. (Solve for $X$ and $Y$)

I originally have two equations such as $AX=b$, $BY=c$. But $b^2+c^2=1$. So it goes to the single equation in the title, and makes $D=$1. It just means $b$ and $c$ have some relationship.

Please give me any suggestions you may have. Approximation, iteration, or any papers you can recommend. I would be so grateful for your help.

If there are any methods can solve using the form $AX=b$,$BY=c$ is also very good. But $b$ and $c$ are not known specifically.

Comment: Are $A,B$ $n \times n$ matrices?

Comment: A and B are the inputs matrix. They can be any dimensions preferable. Yes, they can be n*n.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but won't AX*AX give you the product of two column vectors and the dimensions won't agree?

Comment: I believe (AX)^2 is AX*(AX)^T. Is it correct?

Comment: How is $(Ax)^2$ defined? If it is $(Ax)(Ax)^T$, then $D$ must be a square matrix. If it is $(Ax)^T(Ax)$, then $D$ must be a scalar. So is the square element-wise?